# Is it possible to include several statements in the statement modifier form of if?

Tags: perl

Teaching myself Perl with Project Euler. Anywho,

```
print "Hei" if 1==1;
```

works like a charm.

Is it possible to include several statements before the if, like so

```
{print "4";print="2";} if 4!=2;
```

I'm aware that specific syntax does not work, but I think what I want to do is obvious. Possible or not?

Ps. I'm also aware I could do this with a regular

```
if(){}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add a `do` before it:

```
do {print "4";print="2";} if 4!=2;
```

Note that I wouldn't recommend this kind of code in any real-life scenario. The normal

```
if (condition)
{
    code;
}
```

form is much more familiar, easier to read and debug, and has indentation to guide the reader regarding the flow of control.

Answer (score 10):

1) As mentioned before you can use `do` block:

```
do {print "4";print "2";} if 4!=2;
```

2) You can use comma as in C:

```
print("4"), print("2") if 4!=2;
```

Note in this case you must write with brackets.

3) We know print() returns "1", so:

```
print("4") && print("2") if 4!=2;
```

This will work when 1st command returns true.

4) Using binary operators:

```
print("4") | print("2") if 4!=2;
print("4") & print("2") if 4!=2;
print("4") ^ print("2") if 4!=2;
# etc
```

I think this should work always but its not usual way.

5) Using "array-ing"

```
(print("4"), print("2")) if 4!=2;
```

6) Concatenating

```
print("4") . print("2") if 4!=2;
```

7) `man perlop` and find more ;)

*) Write as a good guy:

```
if( 4!=2 ) {
   print("4");
   print("2");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap it in a `do` block:

```
do {print 1; print 2; } if 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a neat language.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Neat as in interesting .. not neat as in tidy ;-)